# get Client IP in Accounts.OnCreateUser Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to get client IP address in

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {

  var data = {
      "updated_at" : new Date(),
      "registration_ip" : user.connection.clientAddress,
      "recruiter" : "SELF",
      "registration_time" : new Date(),
  };

  _.extend(user.profile, data);
  return user;
});
```

I get Error as :

```
I20170511-19:11:26.792(5.5)? Exception while invoking method 'createUser' 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientAddress' of undefined
```

How can I get Client IP Address here?

Comment: does ```user.connection``` return anything? Also, what happens when you try ```this.connection```?

Comment: @blueren: thanks for reply. It returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Maybe you have to retrieve it when the user is logged in

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to get user IP address.

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attempt) {
    /* Before any checks save user first time login attempt IP address */
    let IPAddress = Global.getNestedValue(attempt, 'connection.httpHeaders.x-forwarded-for');

    if (IPAddress && attempt.user && !attempt.user.firstTimeIP) {
        Meteor.users.update({ _id: attempt.user._id }, { $set: { firstTimeIP: IPAddress } })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and let you know.